# Junk value added to the header when message sent to Azure event hub topic

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-eventhub

I am sending a message to the Azure event hub but the received contains "�$" at the starting of the header value.
Code:

```
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenCredential;
import com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder;
import com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventData;
import com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventDataBatch;
import com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubClientBuilder;
import com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubProducerClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.spring.integration.eventhub.converter.EventHubMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders;

   newMessageHeaders.put("junk", "mock");
    MessageHeaders messageHeaders = new MessageHeaders(newMessageHeaders);
    Message<String> message = new Message<String>() {
      @Override
      public String getPayload() {
        return "MockPayload";
      }

      @Override
      public MessageHeaders getHeaders() {
        return messageHeaders;
      }
    };
    System.setProperty("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET", "secret");
    System.setProperty("AZURE_CLIENT_ID", "client");
    System.setProperty("AZURE_TENANT_ID", "tenant");
    TokenCredential credential = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build();
    EventHubProducerClient eventHubProducerClient = new EventHubClientBuilder()
            .credential("namespaceName.servicebus.windows.net", "mockTopic", credential)
            .buildProducerClient();
    EventHubMessageConverter messageConverter= new EventHubMessageConverter();
    eventHubProducerClient.getEventHubName();
    eventHubProducerClient.getEventHubProperties();
    EventData eventData = messageConverter.fromMessage(message,EntryData.class);
    EventDataBatch batch = eventHubProducerClient.createBatch();
    batch.tryAdd(eventData);
    eventHubProducerClient.send(batch);
    eventHubProducerClient.close();
```

The message received at the azure hub event hub under header the received value is "�$mock"

Comment: Can you help us understand where `Message<String>` and `EventHubMessageConverter` are coming from?   Those do not appear to be SDK types and I suspect that there may be a character encoding issue potentially hiding in that conversion.

Comment: added the imports in class, Message<String> is coming from Sprinframework.Messaging and EventHubMessageConverter is from com.microsoft.azure.spring.integration.eventhub.converter.EventHubMessageConverter;

Comment: The header's value is not a problem when consumed downstream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at: [EventHubMessageConverter.fromString](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/spring/azure-spring-integration-eventhubs/src/main/java/com/azure/spring/integration/eventhub/converter/EventHubMessageConverter.java#L47), it uses `Char.defaultCharset()` where-as, if you call [EventData.getBodyAsString()](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/eventhubs/azure-messaging-eventhubs/src/main/java/com/azure/messaging/eventhubs/EventData.java#L203), we return it UTF-8 decoded.

This could be an encoder mismatch. You are specifying a string as the payload, and this logic here [AbstractAzureMessageConverter: L113-L115](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/e8781bc27c8f2fd7b5d11e756f62833e806723d4/sdk/spring/azure-spring-integration-core/src/main/java/com/azure/spring/integration/core/converter/AbstractAzureMessageConverter.java#L113-L115) calls that `fromString` to encode as `Char.defaultCharset()`.

A couple of solutions:

1. Pass the payload as a set of bytes where you specify the encoding/decoding of the bytes.
2. Deserialize all your input parameters using `Char.defaultCharset()` if you decide to pass it in as a string. The downside to using this is that the defaultCharset changes depending on the locale of your system.